# Sparse data clustering for extremely large dataset

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, sparse-matrix, k-means, r-bigmemory

I have tried using

1. kmeansparse, from sparcl packages (Lack of Memory error)
2. bigkmeans from Biganalytics (Weird error: Couldn't find anything online;         Error in duplicated.default(centers[[length(centers)]]) : 
      duplicated() applies only to vectors)
3. skmean from skmeans (similar results as kmeans)

but I am still not able to get proper clustering for my sparse data. The clusters are not well defined, have overlapping membership for most part. Am I missing something in terms of handling sparse data? 
What kind of pre-processing is suggested for data? should the missing values be marked -1 instead of 0 for clear distinction? Please feel free to ask for more details if you have any ideas that may help.

Comment: K-means (or sparse data clustering) **never worked well for me**. You may have too high expectations. This algorithm is *designed* for continuous dense data...

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for classifying sparse data ?

Comment: Use labeled data, and linear SVMs. That is known to work well.